# Prove or give a counter example for this statement regarding homogeneous polynomials.

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Prove or give a counterexample:

If $f$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $n$ such that $n \geq 2$ and $f$ has its coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$, then there are functions
$a=a(x, y)$ and $b= b(x, y)$ that satisfy $af_{x} + bf_{y} = cf$ (i.e. $af_{x} + bf_{y}$ is equal to a constant multiple of $f$).

P.D. I think the statement is false, but I'm not sure. If anyone can help me I would really appreciate it.

Comment: See Euler's homogeneous function theorem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function#Euler's_theorem

Comment: It is something similar but it is not sufficiently similar or is it? The thing is that the Theorem does not consider arbitrary functions such as $a$ and $b$ also the theorem uses the letter k which is the degree of the function and in this case, it's more general just stating that c is a constant, not necessarily the degree of the function. Maybe I can do something with it, but I'm not sure I can, Thank you regardless :)

Comment: You are saying there exist functions $a$ and $b$ such that ...., and Euler is saying, yes, they exist, and here is what they are.

Comment: Sorry then it seems that I need to read more carefully the Theorem as I clearly didn't understood, Thank you very much :)